# Как очистить поля формы средствами jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть страница в которой есть некоторое количество разных элементов. Надо их вернуть в первоначальное состояние (как при загрузке страницы). Некрасиво же делать так:

```
$('#name').val('');
```

для каждой формы? Есть варианты, как сделать это красивее?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Послушайте, ну сделайте свой модификатор, добавьте всем нужным элементам какой-нибудь класс и очищайте их одной строчкой, как в предыдущем совете. Что за поиски неизвестного-великолепного?

Answer (score 9):

Если есть форма:

```
<form id="myform">
...
</form>
```

то очистить ее можно средствами javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myform').reset();
```

либо jQuery:

```
$('#myform')[0].reset();
```

**Дополнено из комментария.**

Тогда как вариант

```
$(function () {
    $(набор_элементов).each(function () {
        $(this).data('defvalue', this.value);
    });
});
```

И потом вызывать

```
$(набор_элементов).each(function () {
    $(this).val($(this).data('defvalue'));
});
```

Comment: Формы нет.

Comment: var f = document.getElementsByTagName('form'), i = 0;while(f[i]){f[i].reset();++i;} - формы есть. Или $('form').each(function(){this.reset();});

Comment: Не пашет! Нету, я говорю вам, у меня формы; нужные данные, введенные в поля, отправляются через javascript в php.

Comment: Прошу прощения - меня смутило слово "формы" в вопросе. Тогда как вариант - $(function(){$(набор_элементов).each(function(){$(this).data('defvalue', this.value);});}); . И потом вызывать $(набор_элементов).each(function(){$(this).val($(this).data('defvalue'));}); .

Answer (score 5):

```
$("form#id_form").trigger('reset');
```

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте вот такой вариант:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      $('input').val('');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Это конечно круто, но, как мне кажется, должен существовать более универсальный и правильный способ.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - создайте список полей (и, возможно, значений по умолчанию, если не пустые), затем, при необходимости, устанавливайте для всех элементов в списке соответствующие значения... Например так, как предложил ling...

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".reset-form-button").click(function() {

    $("form")[0].reset();

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:
`$("*[tag='tag']").val("").attr("checked", false);`

Answer (score 1):

$('input[name*="имя_поля"]').val('');

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]