# Очистка формы javascript

Tags: javascript, формы

Есть кнопка, которая очищает конкретное поле формы, вот она:

```
<input type="button" value="Очистить" onclick="this.form.elements[\'txt\'].value=\'\'" />
```

Как сделать, чтобы она очищала все поля формы?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11840/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-jquery

Comment: Вот эти два варианта не работают `<input type="button" name="reset_form" value="Reset Form" onclick="document.getElementById(\'myform\').reset();">
 
<input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear Form" onclick="clearForm(this.form);">`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Кнопка очистки всех полей формы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/773379/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Comment: @Linne а форма точно имеет `ID=myform` ?

Comment: Да, конечно, имеет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот это работает:

```
<input type="button" name="clear" value="Clear Form" onclick="document.querySelectorAll(\'input[type=text], textarea\').forEach(el=>el.value = \'\');" />
```